# Infinite product and gamma functions

Tags: calculus, analysis, gamma-function, infinite-product

How could one show or prove that

$\displaystyle \prod _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{(2 n+x-2) (2 n+x-1)}{2 n (2 n+2 x-3)} =\frac{2^{x+1} \Gamma \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (x+2)} ?$

Comment: Legendre Duplication formula to get the $\Gamma(x+1/2)$ into $\Gamma$'s of argument $x$ and $2x$ with $2^{-(2x)}$ factor.  Then use Weirstrass product representation for linear factors within a product.  Because there are two factors in the numerator and denominator, break prod into even and odd parts.

Comment: @skbmoore thanks for the insight but I'm somewhat new to this. I would prefer a detailed answer and solution.